# Java resized JPEG seems to be invalid format for Facebook?

Tags: java, facebook, resize, jpeg

I use a java program to resize my jpg's for imgsrc settings and speed on mobile, etc.

I am using ImageIO and BufferedImage

The file types are TYPE_3BYTE_BRG, and written out that was also that type as a smaller, sans metadata, jpg.

This is the resizing code:

```
    BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(width, newHeight, type);
    Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, width, newHeight, null);
    g.dispose();    
    g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);

    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

The saving code (this calls the above)

```
    BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new 
    File(fileEntry.getParent()+"/"+s));
    int type = originalImage.getType() == 0? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB : originalImage.getType();
    System.out.println("Original is "+type);
                                
            
    f=new File(fileEntry.getParent()+"/"+strippedname+"0x.jpg");
    if(!f.exists())
    {
        System.out.println("Create "+fileEntry.getPath()+"/"+strippedname+"0x.jpg");
        BufferedImage resizeImageJpg = resizeImageWithHint(originalImage, type, 50);
        ImageIO.write(resizeImageJpg, "jpg", f); 
    }
```

Facebook says the Jpg is an invalid format to be processed, and for the life of me, I can't figure out why.

I did open the "offending" jpg for the ogimage in Photoshop, and saved it from there, which still gave an error from FB, but at least it showed on the preview at that point.  FYI until a few months ago, this wasn't an issue.

Any ideas here?

Comment: Why would you call `g.dispose()` before you've finished?

Comment: I honestly dont know, I stole the code from Google, haha.  But it does write a useable JPEG by most systems.

Comment: Also you don't show how you *write* the image to file

Comment: Might be an idea to post an example 'bad' image too

Comment: I have absolutely no understanding how to that in a preserved format?

Comment: A link to the image?

Comment: https://travelingwithrob.com/airportlounge/images/mxpmontale/main1x.jpg

Comment: `file main1x.jpg
main1x.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.02, aspect ratio, density 1x1, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 1000x667, components 3` Looks ok. But you'd need to find out precisely why Facebook complains

Comment: Yeah, there is no information from FB just that it's "invalid".